# Make a for loop in openmp, parallel with matrix/vector manipulations

Tags: c++, openmp

I have this code:

```
scalar State::add(const int N, const int M,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                        vector<scalar>& flmn,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                        vector<scalar>& BSum,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                        const vector<scalar>& prev_flm,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                        const vector<scalar>& prev_bigsum,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                        const vector<scalar>& Qratio,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                        const int test)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  scalar c=1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  #pragma omp parallel for                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  for(int i=1;i<=M;i++)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     flmn.at(i-1) = Qratio.at(i-1)*k1+k2;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
     BSum.at(i-1) = someconstant + somepublicvector.at(1)*flmn.at(i-1);                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
     c *= BSum.at(i-1);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   return c;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

Which at the end I am returning the variable `c`. When use this: "`#pragma omp parallel for`" it definitely won't give me consistent answer since there is always an overlap between the iterations. I wonder how such a combination of matrix or vector manipulations should be parallelized in openmp, and also I would get a consistent results as there is obviously a race condition problem in here?

Comment: It depends on what sorts of containers you are using. Can you provide a Complete, Minimum Working Example?

Comment: What does containers mean? The M in here can be as big as 40,000. and the vectors are initialized this way: const vector<scalar>& prev_flm, const vector<scalar>& prev_bigsum, const vector<scalar>& Qratio.

Comment: The concept you should be looking for is "reduction".

Comment: I updated the code. and thanks, I will look into it to see if I can fix it.

Comment: Reduction is only possible on variable c, but what about the race condition on others?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
    flmn.at(i - 1) = Qratio.at(i - 1) * k1 + k2;
    BSum.at(i - 1) = someconstant + somepublicvector.at(1) * flmn.at(i - 1);
    c *= BSum.at(i - 1);
}
```

A few notes:

1. Don't use `std::vector::at` unless you really need the exception-safe indexing.
2. You are using the same index for each vector, so start at `i=0` rather than the Fortran-style `i=1`.
3. Is M different from the sizes of the vectors being used (i.e., is it a subset)? If not, then it doesn't need to be specified.

---

A possible OpenMP implementation could then be

```
scalar c{1.0};

#pragma omp parallel
{
    const std::size_t nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    const std::size_t chunk_size = M / nthreads;    // WARNING: non-even division case left to user
    const std::size_t tid = omp_get_thread_num();

    #pragma omp for reduction(*:c)
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < chunk_size; j++) {
        const std::size_t i = j + tid * chunk_size;
        flmn[i] = Qratio[i] * k1 + k2;
        BSum[i] = someconstant + somepublicvector[1] * flmn[i];
        c *= BSum[i];
    }
}
```

Note that I have assumed that `nthreads` evenly divides `M`. If it does not, this case needs to be handled separately. If you are using OpenMP 4.0, then I recommend using the `simd` directive since the first two lines are both saxpy operations and can benefit from vectorization. For optimal performance, make sure that `chunk_size` is a multiple of your CPU's cacheline size.

Comment: Why are you doing your own work distribution? You can use a reduction on an omp parallel for, which will remove 3 lines of code and correctly handle cases where M does not divide the number of threads. (Any code which calls omp_get_num_threads() and omp_get_thread_num() is very suspicious...)

Comment: For the basic case I have presented here, it's way overkill. But because OpenMP doesn't use a cache-aware heuristic, it's necessary to get the least amount of false sharing.

Comment: When I get this error: "user defined reduction not found for ‘c’. Does this mean because it is not a normal variable (not from standard defined vars in the language) I have to define the reduction function myself?

Comment: @M.Rez Indeed, if `scalar` isn't a primitive type, then you will need to use a user-defined reduction which requires OpenMP 4.0.

Comment: @Tim if I have over loaded the arithmetic operations on scalar type and I mention it in the omp declaration of the reduction function I get it compiled but I get a segmentation fault in the middle of the run! Just an observation I am not sure if I can make it as a question!

Comment: Tim@2: You can use a chunk_size in an OpenMP schedule, so it can trivially be told to use the same cache-aware heuristic as you are.